# AMP: How can I use PHP values in the "style" attribute?

Tags: css, amp-html

AMP doesn't allow "style" attribute in the html tags but I need to add dynamic PHP values like this within my template markup:

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img1; ?>);"></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img2; ?>);"></div>
```

I don't think `<style amp-custom>` will work in this case as the `background-image` will have different values on pages created using this template.

Comment: can you use a custom class?

Comment: @Johannes no I don't think a custom class will work.

Comment: You can set the different values inside the `<style amp-custom>` if you have the logic for retrieving the images before you echo the `<head>`. But the easy solution is not using background-image and use a regular image and style it like you would have styled the background-image.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have PHP populate a `<style>` tag?

```
<style>
.some-element { color: <?= 'red' ?>; }
</style>
```

...

```
<p class='some-element'>I'm red due to PHP!</p>
```

You can also use an external CSS file if you give it a .php extension and feed the values to it:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='dynamic-css.php?val1=<?= 'foo'; ?>&val2=<?= 'bar' ?>
```

Then in dynamic-css.php:

```
.some-element { color: <?= $_GET['val1'] ?>; font-family: '<?= $_GET['val2'] ?>'}
```

You could also read the values from `$_SESSION` if you store them there first, rather than feed them over `$_GET` when referencing the stylesheet URI.